# Intellij pyspark fails with Java gateway process exited before sending its port number. pyspark runs ok at MacOS level

Tags: python, intellij-idea, pyspark

I am running a simple python example from within Intellij, I have this error that I cant crack having tried all the fixes I can find. (error is on the getOrCreate)

Help would be appreciated from the community of experts!

```
import pandas as pd
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

spark_conf = SparkConf().setAppName("Test")

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

df = pd.DataFrame
mpg = pd.read_csv('/Users/rafe/Documents/Work/Code Examples/Python/mpg.csv')
```

Traceback stack shows an issue with Java, but both pyspark and spark-shell run fine from the MacOS. I have tied all the suggested posts already without success..

```
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/bin/load-spark-env.sh: line 2: /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/bin/load-spark-env.sh: Permission denied
/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/bin/load-spark-env.sh: line 2: exec: /usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/bin/load-spark-env.sh: cannot execute: Undefined error: 0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/rafe/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/IdeaIC2020.2/scratches/PandasExample.py", line 14, in <module>
    sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()
  File "/Users/rafe/venv/snowflake/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 376, in getOrCreate
    SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
  File "/Users/rafe/venv/snowflake/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 133, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
  File "/Users/rafe/venv/snowflake/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 325, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/Users/rafe/venv/snowflake/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 105, in launch_gateway
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

My environment is as follows:

[image]

running Python 3, with the latest version of Intellij Community

```
(base) rafe@Rafes-MacBook-Pro ~ % pyspark
Python 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 11:26:31)
[Clang 10.0.0 ] :: Anaconda, Inc. on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
20/11/30 11:17:56 WARN Utils: Your hostname, Rafes-MacBook-Pro.local resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 192.168.1.252 instead (on interface en0)
20/11/30 11:17:56 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.0.1.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
20/11/30 11:17:56 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.0.1
      /_/

Using Python version 3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020 11:26:31)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>>
```

and spark-shell:

```
(base) rafe@Rafes-MacBook-Pro ~ % spark-shell
20/11/30 11:18:57 WARN Utils: Your hostname, Rafes-MacBook-Pro.local resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 192.168.1.252 instead (on interface en0)
20/11/30 11:18:57 WARN Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/usr/local/Cellar/apache-spark/3.0.1/libexec/jars/spark-unsafe_2.12-3.0.1.jar) to constructor java.nio.DirectByteBuffer(long,int)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
20/11/30 11:18:57 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
Spark context Web UI available at http://192.168.1.252:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1606735142259).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.0.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.12.10 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 11.0.9)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
```

Comment: It seems to be due to Java version incompatibility. Try using Java 8 instead of 11.

Comment: Does the same command (the one IntelliJ runs) run fine in the system terminal?

Comment: Hi Sergey - I dont know how to capture the exact same command IntelliJ runs - can you help with that? and I will update you with the results?

Comment: Hi SaiNagaeswar, I was thinking the same, but when I check it runs fine with Java 11 on the command line:

Comment: Hi Sergey,
Found it out, and YES it runs fine from the command line....